# Drawing a BarChart on a Canvas using GraphicsContext in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, bar-chart, graphicscontext

I am creating a BarChart in JavaFX with random data, and I have a fxml file with a designated canvas that I want to draw the BarChart on.

I am fine on creating the bar chart, but if I have (for example) a barChart object of type BarChart and the canvas has fx:id "canvas", what is the method or code that lets me use GraphicsContext to draw the bar chart on the canvas? I know that to get the GraphicsContext it would be canvas.getGraphicsContext2D, but once I have that GraphicsContext object, what do I do with it to draw my barChart object on the canvas?

Answer (score 2):

You don't paint the [BarChart](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/bar-chart.htm) on a [Canvas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html). Both are of type [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html). Just put the BarChart on your scene and feed it with data.

Comment: I will have the data fed into the BarChart before displaying it. I currently have the Canvas in the center of a BorderPane, so I want the BarChart to appear in the center node of that BorderPane. So are you saying it is impossible to put a BarChart on a Canvas? In that case I will probably go with the StackPane, as there are verified examples. My research supervisor suggested to use a Canvas, which was why I asked about Canvas specifically even though StackPane would be easier.

Comment: Well you could [snapshot the node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) to an image and [draw the image on a canvas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#drawImage-javafx.scene.image.Image-double-double-), but that would be a silly idea, just follow Roland's much better suggestion.

Comment: Yeah I ended up just inserting my barChart into the center node of the borderPane and it worked. Also, @jewelsea I have to thank you because I ended up using your github code involving layered xy charts to help me get more familiar with creating BarCharts :)